Question regarding the conception and calculation of solid angles
Hey fellow physicists,
I've been studying optics and struggling to understand the concept of solid angles. What is it exactly?
Some difficulty also arises when calculating it.
Some sources Say it is the area of a surface divided by the distance from the observer, others say it is the integral of $$ d\Omega = d\theta \cos\phi d\phi $$
but in calculation, contradictions arise between the former and the latter. I've also seen it mathematically expressed as $$\Omega = 2\pi(1-\cos \theta) $$
but even this sometimes contradicts the one before it.
So WHAT IS a solid angle? What does the word "subtended" mean? and why do the methods of calculation differ in various sources? Why is there an apparent contradiction?

Have you consulted Wikipedia? And, since this is math and not physics, did you consider posting on Math SE?

Just as an angle is a ratio of the corresponding arc of a circle to the radius of the circle, so is a solid angle the ratio of the corresponding area to the radius of the circle. In this context, I used "corresponding" instead of word "subtended": just draw a picture, and you'll see what it means. (Work by analogy with the definition of an angle.)

@march so is a solid angle the ratio of the corresponding area to the radius of the circle You mean sphere.

@Ghoster Yes, sphere, sorry. No proof-reading there!


Some sources say it is the area of a surface divided by the distance from the observer

This is clearly incorrect, since the solid angle subtended (which just means "covered") by a surface with a given area depends on the orientation of that surface with respect to the observer. What you may be misremembering is a version of the following definition:

An object's solid angle in steradians is equal to the area of the segment of a unit sphere, centred at the apex, that the object covers.

So if you project a surface onto a sphere centred at the observer and then divide the area of the projection by the square of the sphere's radius, you get the solid angle covered by the surface in steradians.

Others say it is the integral of
$$d\Omega = d\theta \cos\phi d\phi$$

This is the differential formula for calculating surface area on a unit sphere in spherical co-ordinates. Note that $\theta$ is the colatitude i.e. the angle from the North pole.

I've also seen it mathematically expressed as
$$\Omega = 2\pi(1-\cos \theta)$$

And this is the formula for the surface area of a spherical cap on a unit sphere, where $2\theta$ is the angle at the centre of the sphere (and so not the same as $\theta$ in the previous formula).

Why is there an apparent contradiction ?

I think the apparent contradiction arises from you misremembering the definition and misinterpreting the two formulas.
